xDSL transparent bridge over lower quality line
Looking for devices to bridge (transparent) two sites cca 200 m distance over 1 pair (or 2) of telephone cable. Cannot replace the cable, it is underground.
Tried this, but does not work:
https://datainterfaces.com/vdtu2-b110-vdsl2-lan-extender-ethernet-bridge-modem-works-with-fmc-series-chassis-and-vdsm2-1524-minidslam/
This works:
ZyXEL P-791Rv2
https://www.adorama.com/zyp791rv2.html
but cannot be purchased anymore and is rather slow.
What would work for lower quality metalic cables?

What speed do you regard as slow ?

If it's just the cable that can't be replaced, you can do standard 100BASE-TX using the two pairs in telephone cable. Is that insufficient? VDSL2 will also do up to 200 Mb/s.

I regard as a slow speed something less tham 10 Mbps. @RohitGupta

@JMY1000 Doubt I can find enough free functional pairs there.

You only need two pairs for 100BASE-TX.

Ethernet cables are used to connect your computer to your router, and are specifically designed to work over a maximum distance of 328 feet or 100 meters. Moreover, now I have one pair only and possibility of a second one is uncertain.  @JMY1000
